# what is meant by "code attached" in github

Tags: github

Recently I have made a pull request in an open source project hosted in github.Now there is a text "code attached" beside that issue list which I have solved. What is meant by "code attached"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your concern is as follows:

- A GitHub project had an **issue X**
- You fixed it and sent a **pull request Y**
- Now, the **issue X** displays *"code attached"* next to it.

Roughly, from GitHub standpoint, a Pull Request is an issue along with some commits. As such, you can view all the Pull Requests in the Issues tab as well.

What may have happened is that someone else also worked on **issue X** to try and fix it. However, contrarily to you, he didn't opened a pull request but linked his code to **issue X**, thus transforming it into a pull request. Provided I'm right, **issue X** should now also appear in the Pull Request tab along with your **pull request Y**.

Indeed, the **[GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)** exposes a way to transform an issue into a pull request by linking a thread of commits (a branch) to an issue.

A nice tool eases the process of "attaching some code" to an issue. You can check **http://issue2pr.heroku.com** for further information.

As an example this **[issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/866)** has been opened by *joshtriplett* and transformed into a pull request by *arrbee*.

### Update:

Re-reading your question, I now see that it may also be understood in a different way. Let's try this.

My understanding: You sent a spontaneous pull request to a project. This pull request appears in both tabs **Issues** and **Pull Requests**. However, under the **Issues** tab, *"code attached"* is mentioned.

As previously mentioned, A pull request is some kind of "enhanced" issue. It bears a title, a creator, a description and some commits. This explains why your pull request appears under both tabs. *"Code attached"* means that the issue embeds some commits to fix/enhance the project.